# Error while executing script for a TableObject located at the PageFooter section

Tags: c#, .net, report, fastreport

We have a report that displays at the PageFooter which payment way the customer used to pay an order, in that area we have three other TableObjects that are working correctly, but there's one that executes a script to build manually the TableObject, the problem we located is when it executes that script it fails showing the message StackOverflowException in System.Drawing.dll

[image: Visual Studio Error while showing report]

The message on top means the report generation is executing.

The script that I located it fails is this one, if this script is not executing the report displays correctly but without the information we want to display in that TableObject

```
private void TableModalidadPago_ManualBuild(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // get the data source by its name
      DataSourceBase rowData = Report.GetDataSource("DOCUMENTO_MODALIDAD_PAGO");

      // init the data source
      rowData.Init();

      if (rowData.RowCount == 0) 
      {
        TableModalidadPago.Visible = false;
        return;
      }    

      // print the first table row - it is a header
      TableModalidadPago.PrintRow(0);
      TableModalidadPago.PrintColumns();      
      TableModalidadPago.PrintRow(1);
      TableModalidadPago.PrintColumns();


      // now enumerate the data source and print the table body
      while (rowData.HasMoreRows)
      {
        // print the table body  
        TableModalidadPago.PrintRow(2);
        TableModalidadPago.PrintColumns();

        // go next data source row
        rowData.Next();
      }

      TableModalidadPago.CanBreak = false;
      TableModalidadPago.CanGrow = true;  
    }
```

It fails at line

```
TableModalidadPago.PrintRow(0);
```

And if I put the TableObject in other section that is not the PageFooter it works perfectly.

Anyone knows if there's any restriction to execute code at PageFooter or if there's any error at the provided script?

I already posted this information in FastReports forum but still no answer([Link](https://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?showtopic=13547))

Edit: I also created a ticket in FastReports Support centre and still no answer...

**Edit2: 24/06/2016 today I saw they published a new version of the FastReports.Net (2016.3 previous was 2016.2) and I downloaded and install it, after cleaning up my project and tried again, the error still ocurring, with this new version the program just unexplectly closes and doesn't display any error message, I updated my ticket with support center**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The stack overflow error suggests that the while loop may be infinite. Could it actually be failing at the line

```
TableModalidadPago.PrintRow(2);
```

Perhaps you need to remove rows from rowData object once you've printed them?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion/answer, the table only have one row, usually clients only pays using one way, and exactly the same code only fails when is located at the PageFooter, in other sections works perfectly. By the way the line it fails TableModalidadPago.PrintRow(0); code doesnt reach the line provided. Thanks again.